Kernel error while booting (NVME disk) after updating to version 6.5.0-28 generic
I updated from 6.5.0-25 generic to 6.5.0-28 generic and while I still have the 6.5.0-25 generic version as a backup (using it now), whenever I try to boot to 6.5.0-28 generic it gives a "Kernel panic" error.
It can't boot from my NVME, error says it can't find the "partition (0,0)". After it just hangs waiting.
Any clues as to what the update causes to not find the boot partition in NVME?
EDIT: To work normally I removed the -28 package apt remove and I also put it on hold, so I don't get that auto-update apt-mark hold

Did the -28 kernel install correctly?

@OrganicMarble I think so yes, don't remeber any error but I can try to reinstall it. Also, not sure if relevant but I'm using nvdia server drivers.
